# Bound to $\sum_i^n \sqrt{a_i}$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find a bound to this: $\sum_i^n \sqrt{a_i}$ when $a_i$ are positive integers.
I think that the following is true, but can't prove it.
$$\sum_i \sqrt{a_i} \le (\sum_i a_i)^{3/4}$$
I need a tighter bound, can anyone help ?

Comment: With $a_i = 1$ your inequality becomes $n \le n^{3/4}$, which is wrong.

Comment: Why do you need such upper bound? That would help a lot!

Comment: By the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, $$
\sqrt n \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {a_i } } \right)^{1/2} 
$$ is an upper bound.

Comment: This is a part of a question I am working on. I have a planar graph and let say that we sort the vertexes degree from the hist to the lowest, so I need to find a bound on -
$$ \sum_1^{n/2} \sqrt{d_i}$$

Comment: we know that the lowes $d_i >12$